# Remove Python from Devuan/Debian9

Tags: debian

Trying to remove those un-necessary software to make my system smaller and faster.

Looks like there are Python 2.7 and 3 and 3.5 installed,
Is it possible to remove them?

There are posts said the default Python is not-removable and highly dependanted by some X-windows software.

So, my question is:
I am only doing web-surfing on this machine, how do I remove the most of Python out of it?
I definitly don't need 3 versions of Python.

Comment: How does installed python affect on your machine?

Comment: Were you really unable to find anything on how to do this?

Comment: Trying to improve the performance of your computer by deleting packages you don't understand works about as well as improving the performance of your car by opening the hood and cutting out parts you don't recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Python3 is probably just a symlink to python3.5.

Removing python2.7 or python3.5 will probably break your system, since debian highly depends on python. As an example, check apt source code:

```
head -n1 $(which apt)
#!/usr/bin/python3
```